# Ukkonen's suffix tree algorithm in plain English

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, suffix-tree

I feel a bit thick at this point. I've spent days trying to fully wrap my head around suffix tree construction, but because I don't have a mathematical background, many of the explanations elude me as they start to make excessive use of mathematical symbology. The closest to a good explanation that I've found is *[Fast String Searching With Suffix Trees](https://marknelson.us/posts/1996/08/01/suffix-trees.html)*, but he glosses over various points and some aspects of the algorithm remain unclear.

A step-by-step explanation of this algorithm here on Stack Overflow would be invaluable for many others besides me, I'm sure.

For reference, here's Ukkonen's paper on the algorithm: http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1withFigs.pdf

My basic understanding, so far:

- I need to iterate through each prefix P of a given string T
- I need to iterate through each suffix S in prefix P and add that to tree
- To add suffix S to the tree, I need to iterate through each character in S, with the iterations consisting of either walking down an existing branch that starts with the same set of characters C in S and potentially splitting an edge into descendent nodes when I reach a differing character in the suffix, OR if there was no matching edge to walk down. When no matching edge is found to walk down for C, a new leaf edge is created for C.

The basic algorithm appears to be O(n<sup>2</sup>), as is pointed out in most explanations, as we need to step through all of the prefixes, then we need to step through each of the suffixes for each prefix. Ukkonen's algorithm is apparently unique because of the suffix pointer technique he uses, though I think *that* is what I'm having trouble understanding.

I'm also having trouble understanding:

- exactly when and how the "active point" is assigned, used and changed
- what is going on with the canonization aspect of the algorithm
- Why the implementations I've seen need to "fix" bounding variables that they are using

---

Here is the completed **C#** source code. It not only works correctly, but supports automatic canonization and renders a nicer looking text graph of the output. Source code and sample output is at:

> **https://gist.github.com/2373868**

---

**Update 2017-11-04**

After many years I've found a new use for suffix trees, and have implemented the algorithm in **JavaScript**. Gist is below. It should be bug-free. Dump it into a js file, `npm install chalk` from the same location, and then run with node.js to see some colourful output. There's a stripped down version in the same Gist, without any of the debugging code.

> **https://gist.github.com/axefrog/c347bf0f5e0723cbd09b1aaed6ec6fc6**

Comment: I have had quite a lot problems to implement this data structure myself. In the end I found [this](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/dsaaj/enrich/c16/suffix.htm) article and managed to implement it. A great plus for it is that you have a step-by-step example for a quite long string so you get to see what you should do. Please take a look at the article and I will be more then happy to give tips where needed. I am hesitant to gove yet another full-blown explanation as there are alredy quite a few round the internet.

Comment: Did you take a look at the description given in [Dan Gusfield's book](http://www.librarything.com/work/84022)? I found that to be helpful.

Comment: I don't have a copy of that book unfortunately...

Comment: About the implementation and tests at [gist.github.com/2373868](https://gist.github.com/2373868). The code works not properly on string 'dedododeeodo$', because in your output suffix tree we cannot find suffix 'do$'. The reason is that the linked node for active node node #3 is not null but node #1 (check the output for iteration 12).

Comment: The gist does not specify the license - can I change your code and republish under MIT (obviously with attributions)?

Comment: Yep, go for your life. Consider it public domain. As mentioned by another answer on this page, there's a bug that needs fixing anyway.

Comment: "The basic algorithm appears to be O(n2)" -- Good grief. No, the whole point of suffix trees is that their construction is O(n). See suffixtree.org

Comment: @Nathan Ridley: your link suffixtree.nathanridley.com  seems to be dead. Shame, I would have loved to see it.

Comment: maybe this implementation will help others, goto https://code.google.com/p/text-indexing/

Comment: "Consider it public domain" is, perhaps surprisingly a very unhelpful answer.  The reason is that it's actually impossible for you to place the work in the public domain.  Hence your "consider it..." comment underlines the fact that the license is unclear and gives the reader reason to doubt that the status of the work is actually clear to _you_.   If you would like people to be able to use your code, please specify a license for it, choose any license you like (but, unless you're a lawyer, choose a pre-existing license!)

Comment: isn't the naive implementation $O(n^3)$? I think you forgot that for each suffix of a prefix you have to find it first in the trie - which is $O(n)$ as well...

Answer (score 2560, accepted):

The following is an attempt to describe the Ukkonen algorithm by first showing what it does when the string is simple (i.e. does not contain any repeated characters), and then extending it to the full algorithm.

**First, a few preliminary statements.**

1. What we are building, is *basically* like a search trie. So there
   is a root node, edges going out of it leading to new nodes, and
   further edges going out of those, and so forth
2. **But**: Unlike in a search trie, the edge labels are not single
   characters. Instead, each edge is labeled using a pair of integers
   `[from,to]`. These are pointers into the text. In this sense, each
   edge carries a string label of arbitrary length, but takes only O(1)
   space (two pointers).

### Basic principle

I would like to first demonstrate how to create the suffix tree of a
particularly simple string, a string with no repeated characters:

```
abc
```

The algorithm **works in steps, from left to right**. There is **one step for every character of the string**. Each step might involve more than one individual operation, but we will see (see the final observations at the end) that the total number of operations is O(n).

So, we start from the *left*, and first insert only the single character
`a` by creating an edge from the root node (on the left) to a leaf,
and labeling it as `[0,#]`, which means the edge represents the
substring starting at position 0 and ending at *the current end*. I
use the symbol `#` to mean *the current end*, which is at position 1
(right after `a`).

So we have an initial tree, which looks like this:

[image]

And what it means is this:

[image]

Now we progress to position 2 (right after `b`). **Our goal at each step**
is to insert **all suffixes up to the current position**. We do this
by

- expanding the existing `a`-edge to `ab`
- inserting one new edge for `b`

In our representation this looks like

[image]

And what it means is:

[image]

**We observe** two things:

- The edge representation for `ab` is **the same** as it used to be
  in the initial tree: `[0,#]`. Its meaning has automatically changed
  because we updated the current position `#` from 1 to 2.
- Each edge consumes O(1) space, because it consists of only two
  pointers into the text, regardless of how many characters it
  represents.

Next we increment the position again and update the tree by appending
a `c` to every existing edge and inserting one new edge for the new
suffix `c`.

In our representation this looks like

[image]

And what it means is:

[image]

**We observe:**

- The tree is the correct suffix tree *up to the current position*
  after each step
- There are as many steps as there are characters in the text
- The amount of work in each step is O(1), because all existing edges
  are updated automatically by incrementing `#`, and inserting the
  one new edge for the final character can be done in O(1)
  time. Hence for a string of length n, only O(n) time is required.

### First extension: Simple repetitions

Of course this works so nicely only because our string does not
contain any repetitions. We now look at a more realistic string:

```
abcabxabcd
```

It starts with `abc` as in the previous example, then `ab` is repeated
and followed by `x`, and then `abc` is repeated followed by `d`.

**Steps 1 through 3:** After the first 3 steps we have the tree from the previous example:

[image]

**Step 4:** We move `#` to position 4. This implicitly updates all existing
edges to this:

[image]

and we need to insert the final suffix of the current step, `a`, at
the root.

Before we do this, we introduce **two more variables** (in addition to
`#`), which of course have been there all the time but we haven't used
them so far:

- The **active point**, which is a triple
  `(active_node,active_edge,active_length)`
- The `remainder`, which is an integer indicating how many new suffixes
  we need to insert

The exact meaning of these two will become clear soon, but for now
let's just say:

- In the simple `abc` example, the active point was always
  `(root,'\0x',0)`, i.e. `active_node` was the root node, `active_edge` was specified as the null character `'\0x'`, and `active_length` was zero. The effect of this was that the one new edge that
  we inserted in every step was inserted at the root node as a
  freshly created edge. We will see soon why a triple is necessary to
  represent this information.
- The `remainder` was always set to 1 at the beginning of each
  step. The meaning of this was that the number of suffixes we had to
  actively insert at the end of each step was 1 (always just the
  final character).

Now this is going to change. When we insert the current final
character `a` at the root, we notice that there is already an outgoing
edge starting with `a`, specifically: `abca`. Here is what we do in
such a case:

- We **do not** insert a fresh edge `[4,#]` at the root node. Instead we
  simply notice that the suffix `a` is already in our
  tree. It ends in the middle of a longer edge, but we are not
  bothered by that. We just leave things the way they are.
- We **set the active point** to `(root,'a',1)`. That means the active
  point is now somewhere in the middle of outgoing edge of the root node that starts with `a`, specifically, after position 1 on that edge. We
  notice that the edge is specified simply by its first
  character `a`. That suffices because there can be *only one* edge
  starting with any particular character (confirm that this is true after reading through the entire description).
- We also increment `remainder`, so at the beginning of the next step
  it will be 2.

**Observation:** When the final **suffix we need to insert is found to
exist in the tree already**, the tree itself is **not changed** at all (we only update the active point and `remainder`). The tree
is then not an accurate representation of the suffix tree *up to the
current position* any more, but it **contains** all suffixes (because the final
suffix `a` is contained *implicitly*). Hence, apart from updating the
variables (which are all of fixed length, so this is O(1)), there was
**no work** done in this step.

**Step 5:** We update the current position `#` to 5. This
automatically updates the tree to this:

[image]

And **because `remainder` is 2**, we need to insert two final
suffixes of the current position: `ab` and `b`. This is basically because:

- The `a` suffix from the previous step has never been properly
  inserted. So it has *remained*, and since we have progressed one
  step, it has now grown from `a` to `ab`.
- And we need to insert the new final edge `b`.

In practice this means that we go to the active point (which points to
behind the `a` on what is now the `abcab` edge), and insert the
current final character `b`. **But:** Again, it turns out that `b` is
also already present on that same edge.

So, again, we do not change the tree. We simply:

- Update the active point to `(root,'a',2)` (same node and edge
  as before, but now we point to behind the `b`)
- Increment the `remainder` to 3 because we still have not properly
  inserted the final edge from the previous step, and we don't insert
  the current final edge either.

To be clear: We had to insert `ab` and `b` in the current step, but
because `ab` was already found, we updated the active point and did
not even attempt to insert `b`. Why? Because if `ab` is in the tree,
**every suffix** of it (including `b`) must be in the tree,
too. Perhaps only *implicitly*, but it must be there, because of the
way we have built the tree so far.

We proceed to **step 6** by incrementing `#`. The tree is
automatically updated to:

[image]

Because **`remainder` is 3**, we have to insert `abx`, `bx` and
`x`. The active point tells us where `ab` ends, so we only need to
jump there and insert the `x`. Indeed, `x` is not there yet, so we
split the `abcabx` edge and insert an internal node:

[image]

The edge representations are still pointers into the text, so
splitting and inserting an internal node can be done in O(1) time.

So we have dealt with `abx` and decrement `remainder` to 2. Now we
need to insert the next remaining suffix, `bx`. But before we do that
we need to update the active point. The rule for this, after splitting
and inserting an edge, will be called **Rule 1** below, and it applies whenever the
`active_node` is root (we will learn rule 3 for other cases further
below). Here is rule 1:

> After an insertion from root,
>
> - `active_node` remains root
> - `active_edge` is set to the first character of the new suffix we
>     need to insert, i.e. `b`
> - `active_length` is reduced by 1

Hence, the new active-point triple `(root,'b',1)` indicates that the
next insert has to be made at the `bcabx` edge, behind 1 character,
i.e. behind `b`. We can identify the insertion point in O(1) time and
check whether `x` is already present or not. If it was present, we
would end the current step and leave everything the way it is. But `x`
is not present, so we insert it by splitting the edge:

[image]

Again, this took O(1) time and we update `remainder` to 1 and the
active point to `(root,'x',0)` as rule 1 states.

But there is one more thing we need to do. We'll call this **Rule 2:**

> If we split an edge and insert a new node, and if that is *not the
>   first node* created during the current step, we connect the previously
>   inserted node and the new node through a special pointer, a **suffix
>   link**. We will later see why that is useful. Here is what we get, the
>   suffix link is represented as a dotted edge:

[image]

We still need to insert the final suffix of the current step,
`x`. Since the `active_length` component of the active node has fallen
to 0, the final insert is made at the root directly. Since there is no
outgoing edge at the root node starting with `x`, we insert a new
edge:

[image]

As we can see, in the current step all remaining inserts were made.

We proceed to **step 7** by setting `#`=7, which automatically appends the next character,
`a`, to all leaf edges, as always. Then we attempt to insert the new final
character to the active point (the root), and find that it is there
already. So we end the current step without inserting anything and
update the active point to `(root,'a',1)`.

In **step 8**, `#`=8, we append `b`, and as seen before, this only
means we update the active point to `(root,'a',2)` and increment `remainder` without doing
anything else, because `b` is already present. **However,** we notice (in O(1) time) that the active point
is now at the end of an edge. We reflect this by re-setting it to
`(node1,'\0x',0)`. Here, I use `node1` to refer to the
internal node the `ab` edge ends at.

Then, in **step `#`=9**, we need to insert 'c' and this will help us to
understand the final trick:

### Second extension: Using suffix links

As always, the `#` update appends `c` automatically to the leaf edges
and we go to the active point to see if we can insert 'c'. It turns
out 'c' exists already at that edge, so we set the active point to
`(node1,'c',1)`, increment `remainder` and do nothing else.

Now in **step `#`=10**, `remainder` is 4, and so we first need to insert
`abcd` (which remains from 3 steps ago) by inserting `d` at the active
point.

Attempting to insert `d` at the active point causes an edge split in
O(1) time:

[image]

The `active_node`, from which the split was initiated, is marked in
red above. Here is the final rule, **Rule 3:**

> After splitting an edge from an `active_node` that is not the root
>   node, we follow the suffix link going out of that node, if there is
>   any, and reset the `active_node` to the node it points to. If there is
>   no suffix link, we set the `active_node` to the root. `active_edge`
>   and `active_length` remain unchanged.

So the active point is now `(node2,'c',1)`, and `node2` is marked in
red below:

[image]

Since the insertion of `abcd` is complete, we decrement `remainder` to
3 and consider the next remaining suffix of the current step,
`bcd`. Rule 3 has set the active point to just the right node and edge
so inserting `bcd` can be done by simply inserting its final character
`d` at the active point.

Doing this causes another edge split, and **because of rule 2**, we
must create a suffix link from the previously inserted node to the new
one:

[image]

**We observe:** Suffix links enable us to reset the active point so we
  can make the next *remaining insert* at O(1) effort. Look at the
  graph above to confirm that indeed node at label `ab` is linked to
  the node at `b` (its suffix), and the node at `abc` is linked to
  `bc`.

The current step is not finished yet. `remainder` is now 2, and we
need to follow rule 3 to reset the active point again. Since the
current `active_node` (red above) has no suffix link, we reset to
root. The active point is now `(root,'c',1)`.

Hence the next insert occurs at the one outgoing edge of the root node
whose label starts with `c`: `cabxabcd`, behind the first character,
i.e. behind `c`. This causes another split:

[image]

And since this involves the creation of a new internal node,we follow
rule 2 and set a new suffix link from the previously created internal
node:

[image]

(I am using [Graphviz Dot](http://www.graphviz.org/) for these little
graphs. The new suffix link caused dot to re-arrange the existing
edges, so check carefully to confirm that the only thing that was
inserted above is a new suffix link.)

With this, `remainder` can be set to 1 and since the `active_node` is
root, we use rule 1 to update the active point to `(root,'d',0)`. This
means the final insert of the current step is to insert a single `d`
at root:

[image]

That was the final step and we are done. There are number of **final
observations**, though:

- In each step we move `#` forward by 1 position. This automatically
  updates all leaf nodes in O(1) time.
- But it does not deal with a) any suffixes *remaining* from previous
  steps, and b) with the one final character of the current step.
- `remainder` tells us how many additional inserts we need to
  make. These inserts correspond one-to-one to the final suffixes of
  the string that ends at the current position `#`. We consider one
  after the other and make the insert. **Important:** Each insert is
  done in O(1) time since the active point tells us exactly where to
  go, and we need to add only one single character at the active
  point. Why? Because the other characters are *contained implicitly*
  (otherwise the active point would not be where it is).
- After each such insert, we decrement `remainder` and follow the
  suffix link if there is any. If not we go to root (rule 3). If we
  are at root already, we modify the active point using rule 1. In
  any case, it takes only O(1) time.
- If, during one of these inserts, we find that the character we want
  to insert is already there, we don't do anything and end the
  current step, even if `remainder`>0. The reason is that any
  inserts that remain will be suffixes of the one we just tried to
  make. Hence they are all *implicit* in the current tree. The fact
  that `remainder`>0 makes sure we deal with the remaining suffixes
  later.
- What if at the end of the algorithm `remainder`>0? This will be the
  case whenever the end of the text is a substring that occurred
  somewhere before. In that case we must append one extra character
  at the end of the string that has not occurred before. In the
  literature, usually the dollar sign `$` is used as a symbol for
  that. **Why does that matter?** --> If later we use the completed suffix tree to search for suffixes, we must accept matches only if they *end at a leaf*. Otherwise we would get a lot of spurious matches, because there are *many* strings *implicitly* contained in the tree that are not actual suffixes of the main string. Forcing `remainder` to be 0 at the end is essentially a way to ensure that all suffixes end at a leaf node. **However,** if we want to use the tree to search for *general substrings*, not only *suffixes* of the main string, this final step is indeed not required, as suggested by the OP's comment below.
- So what is the complexity of the entire algorithm? If the text is n
  characters in length, there are obviously n steps (or n+1 if we add
  the dollar sign). In each step we either do nothing (other than
  updating the variables), or we make `remainder` inserts, each taking O(1)
  time. Since `remainder` indicates how many times we have done nothing
  in previous steps, and is decremented for every insert that we make
  now, the total number of times we do something is exactly n (or
  n+1). Hence, the total complexity is O(n).
- However, there is one small thing that I did not properly explain:
  It can happen that we follow a suffix link, update the active
  point, and then find that its `active_length` component does not
  work well with the new `active_node`. For example, consider a situation
  like this:

[image]

(The dashed lines indicate the rest of the tree. The dotted line is a
suffix link.)

Now let the active point be `(red,'d',3)`, so it points to the place
behind the `f` on the `defg` edge. Now assume we made the necessary
updates and now follow the suffix link to update the active point
according to rule 3. The new active point is `(green,'d',3)`. However,
the `d`-edge going out of the green node is `de`, so it has only 2
characters. In order to find the correct active point, we obviously
need to follow that edge to the blue node and reset to `(blue,'f',1)`.

In a particularly bad case, the `active_length` could be as large as
`remainder`, which can be as large as n. And it might very well happen
that to find the correct active point, we need not only jump over one
internal node, but perhaps many, up to n in the worst case. Does that
mean the algorithm has a hidden O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity, because
in each step `remainder` is generally O(n), and the post-adjustments
to the active node after following a suffix link could be O(n), too?

No. The reason is that if indeed we have to adjust the active point
(e.g. from green to blue as above), that brings us to a new node that
has its own suffix link, and `active_length` will be reduced. As
we follow down the chain of suffix links we make the remaining inserts, `active_length` can only
decrease, and the number of active-point adjustments we can make on
the way can't be larger than `active_length` at any given time. Since
`active_length` can never be larger than `remainder`, and `remainder`
is O(n) not only in every single step, but the total sum of increments
ever made to `remainder` over the course of the entire process is
O(n) too, the number of active point adjustments is also bounded by
O(n).

Comment: Sorry this ended up a little longer than I hoped. And I realize it explains an number of trivial things we all know, while the difficult parts might still not be perfectly clear. Let's edit it into shape together.

Comment: And I should add that this is _not_ based on the description found in Dan Gusfield's book. It's a new attempt at describing the algorithm by first considering a string with no repetitions and then discussing how repetitions are handled. I hoped that would be more intuitive.

Comment: That is such an awesome answer by jogojapan. And I too faced a difficult time trying to understand and implement it. On a side note, one problem I face is validating my implementation of the  algorithm - on two occasions I ran the code and found bugs through some test cases.

Comment: Thanks @jogojapan, I was able to write a fully-working example thanks to your explanation. I've published the source so hopefully somebody else may find it of use: https://gist.github.com/2373868

Comment: @jogojapan - one question - why do we care if the remainder is greater than zero at the end? I tested ABCABXABCA vs ABCABXABCA$ and the altered tree doesn't seem to have any benefit with regards to searchability.

Comment: @jogojapan thanks, that makes sense now. The final bit I'm looking at, as I think I haven't accounted for it in my code, is the point you're addressing in your final supplementary diagram. My main problem is trying to come up with a character string that will cause this scenario to eventuate, such that I can test for it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @NathanRidley Yes (by the way, that final bit is what Ukkonen calls canonicize). One way to trigger it is to make sure there is a substring that appears three times and ends in a string that appears one more time in yet a different context. E.g. `abcdefabxybcdmnabcdex`. The initial part of `abcd` is repeated in `abxy` (this creates an internal node after `ab`) and again in `abcdex`, and it ends in `bcd`, which appears not only in the `bcdex` context, but also in the `bcdmn` context. After `abcdex` is inserted, we follow the suffix link to insert `bcdex`, and there canonicize will kick in.

Comment: Ah, great thanks! My initial code was horrible and had bugs; I'm writing a newer version at the moment and will post the updated code when it's done, so that hopefully others viewing your explanation will have some working code to follow along with.

Comment: Ok my code has been completely rewritten and now works correctly for all cases, including automatic canonization, plus has a much nicer text graph output. https://gist.github.com/2373868

Comment: One question about the logic surrounding walking down the tree when, after an iteration, the active length is equal to or greater than the length of the current edge. My understanding is that I should walk down the tree, updating the active node for each new node reached and the active edge for the current suffix, and reducing the active length each time until the active length becomes zero or less than the length of the active edge. Doing this, my code correctly handles "abcabxabcd", "mississippi" and "abcdefabxybcdmnabcdex", but fails with "abcadak". Output here: http://bit.ly/HVVVUO

Comment: Your description of the logic (which is the [`canonize`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10097323/777186) function) is accurate. The problem (or one problem) is that in iteration #6, after having dealt with `a{k}`, your code does not go to the root node. In fact the error is in my wording of Rule 3 above: The rule should apply after _any insert_ from an internal node, not only when an edge was split. I will correct it soon... let's see if you find further problems first.

Comment: Great, thanks, that did the trick! I have updated my gist code and sample output and added 5 more sample outputs as well for verification. https://gist.github.com/2373868

Comment: @jogojapan - I think there might be something missing from your instructions. Taking your GraphViz samples, I have updated my code and created a web-based visualiser that generates Dot graphs for every step of the process. http://suffixtree.nathanridley.com - try the string "aabaaa" - note that the suffix a$ is missing from the final graph. Not quite sure why that might happen, any ideas?

Comment: @MrWiredancer Thanks for your suggested edit for step 8. Unfortunately the edit was rejected as too minor by three people before I saw it. But you were right, the active node in step 8 was incorrect. I have corrected it now.

Comment: @jogojapan Thanks a lot for such an understandable approach of Ukkonen's algorithm! Unfortunately, it failed in my case for string "aabaaabb" due to Rule 2, which states that nodes can be connected with a suffix link if they are created **during the current step**. Please, find a more detailed step-by-step description at [link](http://pastebin.com/T6sf1RRi). My source-code in Java: [link](http://pastebin.com/ZuJ3fLvE). If you've got an implementation of ST with your approach, please, could you share it? That would save much time for everyone reading your post. Thank you.

Comment: @makagonov Did you look at Nathan Ridley's implementation?

Comment: @jogojapan I've finally done it with your approach. The problem was that you didn't mention two more cases when we need to add a suffix link: 1) when we create a leaf and 2) when there is an edge existing. Anyway, adding suffix links **ONLY** to the nodes created *during the current step* is not enough. A detailed implementation of your approach in Java is [here](http://pastie.org/5488704). A [problem](http://bit.ly/aHMV58) on Timus Online Judge with good test coverage passed all the tests.

Comment: @jogojapan I've posted an answer below which is based on your approach. I made some modifications to the rules and added one important observation.

Comment: First off, thanks so much for this amazingly detailed explanation. Quick question: Is it possible to carry "payload" in a ukkonen tree, meaning say I want to store a number for each given prefix. I'm unusre since nodes can be implicit ... would it have to be carried on the edge then ? Thank you.

Comment: @ThibautColar Yes, that's difficult. It works easily when the information is attached to a suffix of the string, or a substring that occurs more than once (because this means there must be a branching node in the suffix tree, so you can attach the info to that node). But general substrings / prefixes are only implicit. You could add it to the edge, but there may then more than one infos per edge, and the total size (number of nodes and edges) would, in general, no longer be O(n).

Comment: this is an awesome! I never saw such a great explanation, this is the best answer one can get.

Comment: for Chinese translations visit this: http://www.ibaiyang.org/2013/01/06/suffix-tree-introduction/

Comment: Follow-up question from someone who can't comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303289/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english-clarification

Comment: @jogojapan Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303289/clarification-of-answer-to-stack-overflow-post-ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm) that was just posted seeking clarification about your answer.

Comment: I wish there was a facility in SO to upvote multiple times :) :). Solid answer to an equally solid question!!

Comment: this is a great answer, on one of the more difficult data-structures to understand. this definitely helped me wrap my head around it. thank you.

Comment: Foe big blobs of text, will standard search libraries like Sphinx or Lucene be faster at pattern searching than what can be done using just this algorithm and building a suffix tree and searching it for the pattern?

Comment: @Cupidvogel It depends on what you mean by "pattern search". Sphinx and Lucene use inverted files, so they need to tokenize the text. You can only search for tokens or combinations of tokens. If you are dealing with natural language text and want search results ranking by relevance, then that is most likely what you need, and it will be very fast, and also much smaller (in RAM and on disk) than a suffix tree or suffix array.

Comment: Thanks. So for what purposes are suffix tree bases solution like this are more suitable? By pattern search I simply mean substring search.

Comment: Whenever tokenization isn't possible, e.g. when searching gene sequences rather than natural language, suffix trees (or better suffix arrays) are an option, esp. when the search pattern is very long. They are also good when it comes to identifying patterns like repeated substrings, or substrings that are squares or palindromes and such like. There are various specialized applications in bioinformatics. However, I don't think the Ukkonen algorithm desribed here is used very much in practice these days; I would guess that most people interested in it are interested for educational reasons.

Comment: Yep. In spite of your more than awesome explanation, I am having great difficulty in understanding how it all works.. :)  So say I have to add a search functionality for a text book, say  big sized book at that. You should be able to search text inside it just like you can in a PDF document. Here Ukonen's algo won't be a fit one you say?

Comment: A single book, even if big, is still relatively little content. Also if this is part of a single application run by one user on a single device for individual searches, a search index (Lucene-style or suffix tree) would seem to be overkill. I'd use a direct string search algorithm based on [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). It's quite likely that simply using a string search function from the standard library of your programming language, or linking to something like "grep" would work perfectly.

Comment: It would be just awesome to have similarly structured answer to the Dijkstra's shortest-path algorithm.

Comment: @Pixar It would be awesome to have a website that is dedicated to detailed, plain-english explanations of algorithms like this.

Comment: A note on this:

"However, if we want to use the tree to search for general substrings, not only suffixes of the main string, this final step is indeed not required, as suggested by the OP's comment below."

In general, you can use a finalized suffix tree to report the number of occurrences of a particular substring by just following the path from the root to a particular node or edge defined by that substring, then counting the number of leaves in that subtree.

But that property doesn't hold for non-finalized suffixtrees.

Comment: Really appreciate. This is the most understandable explanation of Ukkonen's algorithm I can found on web. I try to implement based on this but found out there are some corner cases missing, because the suffix link does not set up correctly. like "cdddcdc"

Comment: This is a great explanation but I understood it more clearly and quickly from here https://youtu.be/F3nbY3hIDLQ?t=37m19s ,this is a lecture from MIT open courseware, he explains compressed trie first and then goes on explain suffix trees. I will say this is a must watch.

Comment: Fantastic writing, @jogojapan. As far as I can tell, Gusfield's String Algorithms book takes the approach of starting with a fully correct but inefficient cubic-time algorithm and progressively improving its performance to linear. This answer starts with a linear algorithm that only handles trivial cases (strings with no repetition) then adds logic to handle progressively more difficult cases. Nice work!

Comment: @jogojapan Came back to this after 5+ years and have added a JS implementation, in case you're ever looking for a working reference (linked in the question).

Comment: Lost you at step four, where `ac` comes from?

Comment: @exebook I don't see any `ac` in step 4... Can you explain what you are referring to?

Comment: @jogojapan sorry for this confusion, I was scrolling for too long to get to the last comment and by that time mistook ac for ca.

Comment: @exebook The `#` is a variable that in step 4 takes on the meaning of `4`, because that is the current position.  So edge `[2,#]` takes on the meaning of `[2,4]`, and the string beginning at position 2 and ending at position 4 is `ca` (because `c` is the 3rd, and `a` the 4th character of the string).

Comment: When there is no a suffix link we set the active node to the root node, in this case the down walk on the tree could be more than the ramainder? Besides, if in a phase with ramonder r we insert k nodes for the firste node inserted we could walk down for r-1 for the second r-2 and so on. Then we have r-1+...r-k steps, how to achieve from that an overall O(n)?

Comment: Very good explanation; *But*, I've found the rules very unhelpful. As you've mentioned and gave an example that we may need to update the active node after going through a suffix link, it's actually more complicated than that. We need to generalize that idea. When ever going through a suffix link, or even when a node doesn't have a suffix link, we need to use dfs (as some calls it "walk down".) Consider the word "aabbabab$". At some point, you'll need to go from a node with prefix "bab" to a node with prefix "ab". The suffix link won't exist till that point. The only way is to use dfs.

Comment: It seems activeNode means suffixNode that also contains the max proper suffix of the currentSuffix as prefix, for, e.g., in case of "abc" the activeNode represents the '\0' (null node) or the empty string, in case of "abca", this changes to the node that starts with 'a' as that contains the max suffix ("a") of the current suffix ("abca") as prefix Renaming activeNode to nodeWithMaxProperSuffixOfCurrentSuffixAsPrefix might be a good idea.

Comment: Why are you making it seem like there's a 3-tuple of variables plus a remainder variable, instead of saying there's 4 variables?

Comment: @Jake The triple (i.e. the `active_point` refers to a position inside the suffix tree, whereas the `remainder` refers to the input string. I just wanted to keep these two separate conceptually. Technically of course you do it as a quadruple, or as four separate variables, or anything else.

Answer (score 138):

I tried to implement the Suffix Tree with the approach given in jogojapan's answer, but it didn't work for some cases due to wording used for the rules. Moreover, I've mentioned that nobody managed to implement an absolutely correct suffix tree using this approach. Below I will write an "overview" of jogojapan's answer with some modifications to the rules. I will also describe the case when we forget to create ***important*** suffix links.

**Additional variables used**

1. **active point** - a triple (active_node; active_edge; active_length), showing from where we must start inserting a new suffix.
2. **remainder** - shows the number of suffixes we must add *explicitly*. For instance, if our word is 'abcaabca', and remainder = 3, it means we must process 3 last suffixes: **bca**, **ca** and **a**.

Let's use a concept of an **internal node** - all the nodes, except the *root* and the *leafs* are **internal nodes**.

**Observation 1**

When the final suffix we need to insert is found to exist in the tree already, the tree itself is not changed at all (we only update the `active point` and `remainder`).

**Observation 2**

If at some point `active_length` is greater or equal to the length of current edge (`edge_length`), we move our `active point` down until `edge_length` is strictly greater than `active_length`.

Now, let's redefine the rules:

**Rule 1**

> If after an insertion from the *active node* = *root*, the *active length* is greater than 0, then:
>
> 1. *active node* is not changed
> 2. *active length* is decremented
> 3. *active edge* is shifted right (to the first character of the next suffix we must insert)

**Rule 2**

> If we create a new *internal node* **OR** make an inserter from an *internal node*, and this is not the first **SUCH** *internal node* at current step, then we link the previous **SUCH** node with **THIS** one through a *suffix link*.

This definition of the `Rule 2` is different from jogojapan', as here we take into account not only the *newly created* internal nodes, but also the internal nodes, from which we make an insertion.

**Rule 3**

> After an insert from the *active node* which is not the *root* node, we must follow the suffix link and set the *active node* to the node it points to. If there is no a suffix link, set the *active node* to the *root* node. Either way, *active edge* and *active length* stay unchanged.

In this definition of `Rule 3` we also consider the inserts of leaf nodes (not only split-nodes).

**And finally, Observation 3:**

When the symbol we want to add to the tree is already on the edge, we, according to `Observation 1`, update only `active point` and `remainder`, leaving the tree unchanged. **BUT** if there is an *internal node* marked as *needing suffix link*, we must connect that node with our current `active node` through a suffix link.

Let's look at the example of a suffix tree for **cdddcdc** if we add a suffix link in such case and if we don't:

1. If we **DON'T** connect the nodes through a suffix link:

   - before adding the last letter **c**:

   [image]

   - after adding the last letter **c**:

   [image]
2. If we **DO** connect the nodes through a suffix link:

   - before adding the last letter **c**:

   [image]

   - after adding the last letter **c**:

   [image]

Seems like there is no significant difference: in the second case there are two more suffix links. But these suffix links are *correct*, and one of them - from the blue node to the red one - is very **important** for our approach with **active point**. The problem is that if we don't put a suffix link here, later, when we add some new letters to the tree, we might omit adding some nodes to the tree due to the `Rule 3`, because, according to it, if there's no a suffix link, then we must put the `active_node` to the root.

When we were adding the last letter to the tree, the red node had **already existed** before we made an insert from the blue node (the edge labled **'c'**). As there was an insert from the blue node, we mark it as *needing a suffix link*. Then, relying on the **active point** approach, the `active node` was set to the red node. But we don't make an insert from the red node, as the letter **'c'** is already on the edge. Does it mean that the blue node must be left without a suffix link? No, we must connect the blue node with the red one through a suffix link. Why is it correct? Because the **active point** approach guarantees that we get to a right place, i.e., to the next place where we must process an insert of a **shorter** suffix.

Finally, here are my implementations of the Suffix Tree:

1. [Java](https://gist.github.com/makagonov/22ab3675e3fc0031314e8535ffcbee2c)
2. [C++](https://gist.github.com/makagonov/f7ed8ce729da72621b321f0ab547debb)

Hope that this "overview" combined with jogojapan's detailed answer will help somebody to implement his own Suffix Tree.

Comment: Thanks very much and +1 for you effort. I am sure you are right.. although I don't have the time to think about the details right away. I'll check later and possibly modify my answer then as well.

Comment: Thanks so much, it really helped. Though, could you be more specific on Observation 3? For instance, giving the diagrams of the 2 steps that introduce the new suffix link. Is the node linked the active node? (as we don't actually insert the 2nd node)

Comment: @makagonov Hey can you help me build suffix tree for your string "cdddcdc" I am bit confused doing so (the starting steps).

Comment: As for rule 3, a smart way is to set the suffix link of root to root itself, and (in default) set the suffix link of every node to root. Thus we can avoid the conditioning and just follow the suffix link.

Comment: Great explanation! Just one thing I'd like to add. I am still trying to understand, but as far as I understood, this explanation skips one edge case: "abca". The case where the last digit was repeated in the string before. In that case we need to append an end character to the string, sth like '$'. Check the 5th paragraph in http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/dsaaj/enrich/c16/suffix.htm

Comment: Are you sure? You says 'we might omit adding some nodes to the tree due to the Rule 3', but your example can't show that. Without your new link, I can still get right tree, but just with one more step. Can you come up with another example show that? Also @jogojapan?

Comment: Hello @makagonov, maybe this is a bad place to ask, but i ported your example code to Rust for my project. It running like a charm, however, your code didn't have a license attach to it, so I don't know if I could actually use it in my projects or not. **Please clarify the permission of your code, thank you!** My port is here: https://gist.github.com/raincious/cb0b6b48efc3c63d6532c329fe362112

Comment: Is there any case that proves this extra action is required? I have a guess. In rule 3, after the active node is set to the root, the tuple, `(active_node; active_edge; active_length)`, should be updated to find the correct `active_node`. The function of this process is as the same as the function of the extra suffix link that this post mentioned.

Comment: `aabaacaad` is one of the cases that shows adding extra suffix link can reduce the times of updating the triple. The conclusion in the last two paragraphs of the post of jogojapan is wrong. If we do not add the suffix links this post mentioned, the average time complexity should be O(nlong(n)) or more. Because it takes extra time to walk the tree to find the correct `active_node`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation!

Answer (score 22):

Apologies if my answer seems redundant, but I implemented Ukkonen's algorithm recently, and found myself struggling with it for days; I had to read through multiple papers on the subject to understand the why and how of some core aspects of the algorithm.

I found the 'rules' approach of previous answers unhelpful for understanding the underlying *reasons*, so I've written everything below focusing solely on the pragmatics. If you've struggled with following other explanations, just like I did, perhaps my supplemental explanation will make it 'click' for you.

I published my C# implementation here: https://github.com/baratgabor/SuffixTree

*Please note that I'm not an expert on this subject, so the following sections may contain inaccuracies (or worse). If you encounter any, feel free to edit.*

### Prerequisites

The starting point of the following explanation assumes you're familiar with the content and use of suffix trees, and the characteristics of Ukkonen's algorithm, e.g. how you're extending the suffix tree character by character, from start to end. Basically, I assume you've read some of the other explanations already.

(However, I did have to add some basic narrative for the flow, so the beginning might indeed feel redundant.)

The most interesting part is the *explanation on the difference between using suffix links and rescanning from the root*. This is what gave me a lot of bugs and headaches in my implementation.

### Open-ended leaf nodes and their limitations

I'm sure you already know that the most fundamental 'trick' is to realize we can just leave the end of the suffixes 'open', i.e. referencing the current length of the string instead of setting the end to a static value. This way when we add additional characters, those characters will be implicitly added to all suffix labels, without having to visit and update all of them.

But this open ending of suffixes – for obvious reasons – works only for nodes that represent the end of the string, i.e. the leaf nodes in the tree structure. The branching operations we execute on the tree (the addition of new branch nodes and leaf nodes) won't propagate automatically everywhere they need to.

*It's probably elementary, and wouldn't require mention, that repeated substrings don't appear explicitly in the tree, since the tree already contains these by virtue of them being repetitions; however, when the repetitive substring ends by encountering a non-repeating character, we need to create a branching at that point to represent the divergence from that point onwards.*

For example in case of the string *'ABCXABCY'* (see below), a branching to *X* and *Y* needs to be added to three different suffixes, *ABC*, *BC* and *C*; otherwise it wouldn't be a valid suffix tree, and we couldn't find all substrings of the string by matching characters from the root downwards.

Once again, to emphasize – *any* operation we execute on a suffix in the tree needs to be reflected by its consecutive suffixes as well (e.g. ABC > BC > C), otherwise they simply cease to be valid suffixes.

[image: Repeating branching in suffixes]

But even if we accept that we have to do these manual updates, how do we know how many suffixes need to be updated? Since, when we add the repeated character *A* (and the rest of the repeated characters in succession), we have no idea yet when/where do we need to split the suffix into two branches. The need to split is ascertained only when we encounter the first non-repeating character, in this case *Y* (instead of the *X* that already exists in the tree).

What we can do is to match the longest repeated string we can, and count how many of its suffixes we need to update later. This is what *'remainder'* stands for.

### The concept of 'remainder' and 'rescanning'

The variable `remainder` tells us how many repeated characters we added implicitly, without branching; i.e. how many suffixes we need to visit to repeat the branching operation once we found the first character that we cannot match. This essentially equals to how many characters 'deep' we are in the tree from its root.

So, staying with the previous example of the string *ABCXABCY*, we match the repeated *ABC* part 'implicitly', incrementing `remainder` each time, which results in remainder of 3. Then we encounter the non-repeating character *'Y'*. Here we split the previously added *ABCX* into *ABC*->*X* and *ABC*->*Y*. Then we decrement `remainder` from 3 to 2, because we already took care of the *ABC* branching. Now we repeat the operation by matching the last 2 characters – *BC* – from the root to reach the point where we need to split, and we split *BCX* too into *BC*->*X* and *BC*->*Y*. Again, we decrement `remainder` to 1, and repeat the operation; until the `remainder` is 0. Lastly, we need to add the current character (*Y*) itself to the root as well.

This operation, following the consecutive suffixes from the root simply to reach the point where we need to do an operation is what's called *'rescanning'* in Ukkonen's algorithm, and typically this is the most expensive part of the algorithm. Imagine a longer string where you need to 'rescan' long substrings, across many dozens of nodes (we'll discuss this later), potentially thousands of times.

As a solution, we introduce what we call *'suffix links'*.

### The concept of 'suffix links'

Suffix links basically point to the positions we'd normally have to *'rescan'* to, so instead of the expensive rescan operation we can simply jump to the linked position, do our work, jump to the next linked position, and repeat – until there are no more positions to update.

Of course one big question is how to add these links. The existing answer is that we can add the links when we insert new branch nodes, utilizing the fact that, in each extension of the tree, the branch nodes are naturally created one after another in the exact order we'd need to link them together. Though, we have to link from the last created branch node (the longest suffix) to the previously created one, so we need to cache the last we create, link that to the next one we create, and cache the newly created one.

One consequence is that we actually often don't have suffix links to follow, because the given branch node was just created. In these cases we have to still fall back to the aforementioned *'rescanning'* from root. This is why, after an insertion, you're instructed to either use the suffix link, or jump to root.

(Or alternatively, if you're storing parent pointers in the nodes, you can try to follow the parents, check if they have a link, and use that. I found that this is very rarely mentioned, but *the suffix link usage is not set in stones.* There are multiple possible approaches, and if you understand the underlying mechanism you can implement one that fits your needs the best.)

### The concept of 'active point'

So far we discussed multiple efficient tools for building the tree, and vaguely referred to traversing over multiple edges and nodes, but haven't yet explored the corresponding consequences and complexities.

The previously explained concept of *'remainder'* is useful for keeping track where we are in the tree, but we have to realize it doesn't store enough information.

Firstly, we always reside on a specific edge of a node, so we need to store the edge information. We shall call this *'active edge'*.

Secondly, even after adding the edge information, we still have no way to identify a position that is farther down in the tree, and not directly connected to the *root* node. So we need to store the node as well. Let's call this *'active node'*.

Lastly, we can notice that the *'remainder'* is inadequate to identify a position on an edge that is not directly connected to root, because *'remainder'* is the length of the entire route; and we probably don't want to bother with remembering and subtracting the length of the previous edges. So we need a representation that is essentially the *remainder on the current edge*. This is what we call *'active length'*.

This leads to what we call *'active point'* – a package of three variables that contain all the information we need to maintain about our position in the tree:

`Active Point = (Active Node, Active Edge, Active Length)`

You can observe on the following image how the matched route of *ABCABD* consists of 2 characters on the edge *AB* (from *root*), plus 4 characters on the edge *CABDABCABD* (from node 4) – resulting in a *'remainder'* of 6 characters. So, our current position can be identified as *Active Node 4, Active Edge C, Active Length 4*.

[image: Remainder and Active Point]

Another important role of the *'active point'* is that it provides an abstraction layer for our algorithm, meaning that parts of our algorithm can do their work on the *'active point'*, irrespective of whether that active point is in the root or anywhere else. This makes it easy to implement the use of suffix links in our algorithm in a clean and straight-forward way.

### Differences of rescanning vs using suffix links

Now, the tricky part, something that – in my experience – can cause plenty of bugs and headaches, and is poorly explained in most sources, is the difference in processing the suffix link cases vs the rescan cases.

Consider the following example of the string *'AAAABAAAABAAC'*:

[image: Remainder across multiple edges]

You can observe above how the *'remainder'* of 7 corresponds to the total sum of characters from root, while *'active length'* of 4 corresponds to the sum of matched characters from the active edge of the active node.

Now, after executing a branching operation at the active point, our active node might or might not contain a suffix link.

**If a suffix link is present:** We only need to process the *'active length'* portion. The *'remainder'* is irrelevant, because *the node where we jump to via the suffix link already encodes the correct 'remainder' implicitly*, simply by virtue of being in the tree where it is.

**If a suffix link is NOT present:** We need to *'rescan'* from zero/root, which means processing the whole suffix from the beginning. To this end we have to use the whole *'remainder'* as the basis of rescanning.

### Example comparison of processing with and without a suffix link

Consider what happens at the next step of the example above. Let's compare how to achieve the same result – i.e. moving to the next suffix to process – with and without a suffix link.

#### **Using *'suffix link'***

[image: Reaching consecutive suffixes via suffix links]

Notice that if we use a suffix link, we are automatically 'at the right place'. Which is often not strictly true due to the fact that the *'active length'* can be 'incompatible' with the new position.

In the case above, since the *'active length'* is 4, we're working with the suffix '*ABAA'*, starting at the linked Node 4. But after finding the edge that corresponds to the first character of the suffix (*'A'*), we notice that our *'active length'* overflows this edge by 3 characters. So we jump over the full edge, to the next node, and decrement *'active length'* by the characters we consumed with the jump.

Then, after we found the next edge *'B'*, corresponding to the decremented suffix *'BAA*', we finally note that the edge length is larger than the remaining *'active length'* of 3, which means we found the right place.

*Please note that it seems this operation is usually not referred to as 'rescanning', even though to me it seems it's the direct equivalent of rescanning, just with a shortened length and a non-root starting point.*

#### **Using *'rescan'***

[image: Reaching consecutive suffixes via rescanning]

Notice that if we use a traditional 'rescan' operation (here pretending we didn't have a suffix link), we start at the top of the tree, at root, and we have to work our way down again to the right place, following along the entire length of the current suffix.

The length of this suffix is the *'remainder'* we discussed before. We have to consume the entirety of this remainder, until it reaches zero. This might (and often does) include jumping through multiple nodes, at each jump decreasing the remainder by the length of the edge we jumped through. Then finally, we reach an edge that is longer than our remaining *'remainder'*; here we set the active edge to the given edge, set *'active length'* to remaining *'remainder*', and we're done.

Note, however, that the actual *'remainder'* variable needs to be preserved, and only decremented after each node insertion. So what I described above assumed using a separate variable initialized to *'remainder'*.

**Notes on suffix links & rescans**

1) Notice that both methods lead to the same result. Suffix link jumping is, however, significantly faster in most cases; that's the whole rationale behind suffix links.

2) The actual algorithmic implementations don't need to differ. As I mentioned above, even in the case of using the suffix link, the *'active length'* is often not compatible with the linked position, since that branch of the tree might contain additional branching. So essentially you just have to use *'active length'* instead of *'remainder'*, and execute the same rescanning logic until you find an edge that is shorter than your remaining suffix length.

3) One important remark pertaining to performance is that there is no need to check each and every character during rescanning. Due to the way a valid suffix tree is built, we can safely assume that the characters match. So you're mostly counting the lengths, and the only need for character equivalence checking arises when we jump to a new edge, since edges are identified by their first character (which is always unique in the context of a given node). This means that 'rescanning' logic is different than full string matching logic (i.e. searching for a substring in the tree).

4) The original suffix linking described here is just *one of the possible approaches*. For example [NJ Larsson et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.0457.pdf) names this approach as *Node-Oriented Top-Down*, and compares it to *Node-Oriented Bottom-Up* and two *Edge-Oriented* varieties. The different approaches have different typical and worst case performances, requirements, limitations, etc., but it generally seems that *Edge-Oriented* approaches are an overall improvement to the original.

Answer (score 10):

@jogojapan you brought awesome explanation and visualisation. But as @makagonov mentioned it's missing some rules regarding setting suffix links. It's visible in nice way when going step by step on http://brenden.github.io/ukkonen-animation/ through word 'aabaaabb'. When you go from step 10 to step 11, there is no suffix link from node 5 to node 2 but active point suddenly moves there.

@makagonov since I live in Java world I also tried to follow your implementation to grasp ST building workflow but it was hard to me because of:

- combining edges with nodes
- using index pointers instead of references
- breaks statements;
- continue statements;

So I ended up with such implementation in Java which I hope reflects all steps in clearer way and will reduce learning time for other Java people:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ST {

  public class Node {
    private final int id;
    private final Map<Character, Edge> edges;
    private Node slink;

    public Node(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.edges = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void setSlink(final Node slink) {
        this.slink = slink;
    }

    public Map<Character, Edge> getEdges() {
        return this.edges;
    }

    public Node getSlink() {
        return this.slink;
    }

    public String toString(final String word) {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("{")
                .append("\"id\"")
                .append(":")
                .append(this.id)
                .append(",")
                .append("\"slink\"")
                .append(":")
                .append(this.slink != null ? this.slink.id : null)
                .append(",")
                .append("\"edges\"")
                .append(":")
                .append(edgesToString(word))
                .append("}")
                .toString();
    }

    private StringBuilder edgesToString(final String word) {
        final StringBuilder edgesStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        edgesStringBuilder.append("{");
        for(final Map.Entry<Character, Edge> entry : this.edges.entrySet()) {
            edgesStringBuilder.append("\"")
                    .append(entry.getKey())
                    .append("\"")
                    .append(":")
                    .append(entry.getValue().toString(word))
                    .append(",");
        }
        if(!this.edges.isEmpty()) {
            edgesStringBuilder.deleteCharAt(edgesStringBuilder.length() - 1);
        }
        edgesStringBuilder.append("}");
        return edgesStringBuilder;
    }

    public boolean contains(final String word, final String suffix) {
        return !suffix.isEmpty()
                && this.edges.containsKey(suffix.charAt(0))
                && this.edges.get(suffix.charAt(0)).contains(word, suffix);
    }
  }

  public class Edge {
    private final int from;
    private final int to;
    private final Node next;

    public Edge(final int from, final int to, final Node next) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getFrom() {
        return this.from;
    }

    public int getTo() {
        return this.to;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return this.to - this.from;
    }

    public String toString(final String word) {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("{")
                .append("\"content\"")
                .append(":")
                .append("\"")
                .append(word.substring(this.from, this.to))
                .append("\"")
                .append(",")
                .append("\"next\"")
                .append(":")
                .append(this.next != null ? this.next.toString(word) : null)
                .append("}")
                .toString();
    }

    public boolean contains(final String word, final String suffix) {
        if(this.next == null) {
            return word.substring(this.from, this.to).equals(suffix);
        }
        return suffix.startsWith(word.substring(this.from,
                this.to)) && this.next.contains(word, suffix.substring(this.to - this.from));
    }
  }

  public class ActivePoint {
    private final Node activeNode;
    private final Character activeEdgeFirstCharacter;
    private final int activeLength;

    public ActivePoint(final Node activeNode,
                       final Character activeEdgeFirstCharacter,
                       final int activeLength) {
        this.activeNode = activeNode;
        this.activeEdgeFirstCharacter = activeEdgeFirstCharacter;
        this.activeLength = activeLength;
    }

    private Edge getActiveEdge() {
        return this.activeNode.getEdges().get(this.activeEdgeFirstCharacter);
    }

    public boolean pointsToActiveNode() {
        return this.activeLength == 0;
    }

    public boolean activeNodeIs(final Node node) {
        return this.activeNode == node;
    }

    public boolean activeNodeHasEdgeStartingWith(final char character) {
        return this.activeNode.getEdges().containsKey(character);
    }

    public boolean activeNodeHasSlink() {
        return this.activeNode.getSlink() != null;
    }

    public boolean pointsToOnActiveEdge(final String word, final char character) {
        return word.charAt(this.getActiveEdge().getFrom() + this.activeLength) == character;
    }

    public boolean pointsToTheEndOfActiveEdge() {
        return this.getActiveEdge().getLength() == this.activeLength;
    }

    public boolean pointsAfterTheEndOfActiveEdge() {
        return this.getActiveEdge().getLength() < this.activeLength;
    }

    public ActivePoint moveToEdgeStartingWithAndByOne(final char character) {
        return new ActivePoint(this.activeNode, character, 1);
    }

    public ActivePoint moveToNextNodeOfActiveEdge() {
        return new ActivePoint(this.getActiveEdge().getNext(), null, 0);
    }

    public ActivePoint moveToSlink() {
        return new ActivePoint(this.activeNode.getSlink(),
                this.activeEdgeFirstCharacter,
                this.activeLength);
    }

    public ActivePoint moveTo(final Node node) {
        return new ActivePoint(node, this.activeEdgeFirstCharacter, this.activeLength);
    }

    public ActivePoint moveByOneCharacter() {
        return new ActivePoint(this.activeNode,
                this.activeEdgeFirstCharacter,
                this.activeLength + 1);
    }

    public ActivePoint moveToEdgeStartingWithAndByActiveLengthMinusOne(final Node node,
                                                                       final char character) {
        return new ActivePoint(node, character, this.activeLength - 1);
    }

    public ActivePoint moveToNextNodeOfActiveEdge(final String word, final int index) {
        return new ActivePoint(this.getActiveEdge().getNext(),
                word.charAt(index - this.activeLength + this.getActiveEdge().getLength()),
                this.activeLength - this.getActiveEdge().getLength());
    }

    public void addEdgeToActiveNode(final char character, final Edge edge) {
        this.activeNode.getEdges().put(character, edge);
    }

    public void splitActiveEdge(final String word,
                                final Node nodeToAdd,
                                final int index,
                                final char character) {
        final Edge activeEdgeToSplit = this.getActiveEdge();
        final Edge splittedEdge = new Edge(activeEdgeToSplit.getFrom(),
                activeEdgeToSplit.getFrom() + this.activeLength,
                nodeToAdd);
        nodeToAdd.getEdges().put(word.charAt(activeEdgeToSplit.getFrom() + this.activeLength),
                new Edge(activeEdgeToSplit.getFrom() + this.activeLength,
                        activeEdgeToSplit.getTo(),
                        activeEdgeToSplit.getNext()));
        nodeToAdd.getEdges().put(character, new Edge(index, word.length(), null));
        this.activeNode.getEdges().put(this.activeEdgeFirstCharacter, splittedEdge);
    }

    public Node setSlinkTo(final Node previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode,
                           final Node node) {
        if(previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode != null) {
            previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode.setSlink(node);
        }
        return node;
    }

    public Node setSlinkToActiveNode(final Node previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode) {
        return setSlinkTo(previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode, this.activeNode);
    }
  }

  private static int idGenerator;

  private final String word;
  private final Node root;
  private ActivePoint activePoint;
  private int remainder;

  public ST(final String word) {
    this.word = word;
    this.root = new Node(idGenerator++);
    this.activePoint = new ActivePoint(this.root, null, 0);
    this.remainder = 0;
    build();
  }

  private void build() {
    for(int i = 0; i < this.word.length(); i++) {
        add(i, this.word.charAt(i));
    }
  }

  private void add(final int index, final char character) {
    this.remainder++;
    boolean characterFoundInTheTree = false;
    Node previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode = null;
    while(!characterFoundInTheTree && this.remainder > 0) {
        if(this.activePoint.pointsToActiveNode()) {
            if(this.activePoint.activeNodeHasEdgeStartingWith(character)) {
                activeNodeHasEdgeStartingWithCharacter(character, previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode);
                characterFoundInTheTree = true;
            }
            else {
                if(this.activePoint.activeNodeIs(this.root)) {
                    rootNodeHasNotEdgeStartingWithCharacter(index, character);
                }
                else {
                    previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode = internalNodeHasNotEdgeStartingWithCharacter(index,
                            character, previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if(this.activePoint.pointsToOnActiveEdge(this.word, character)) {
                activeEdgeHasCharacter();
                characterFoundInTheTree = true;
            }
            else {
                if(this.activePoint.activeNodeIs(this.root)) {
                    previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode = edgeFromRootNodeHasNotCharacter(index,
                            character,
                            previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode);
                }
                else {
                    previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode = edgeFromInternalNodeHasNotCharacter(index,
                            character,
                            previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }

  private void activeNodeHasEdgeStartingWithCharacter(final char character,
                                                    final Node previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode) {
    this.activePoint.setSlinkToActiveNode(previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode);
    this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveToEdgeStartingWithAndByOne(character);
    if(this.activePoint.pointsToTheEndOfActiveEdge()) {
        this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveToNextNodeOfActiveEdge();
    }
  }

  private void rootNodeHasNotEdgeStartingWithCharacter(final int index, final char character) {
    this.activePoint.addEdgeToActiveNode(character, new Edge(index, this.word.length(), null));
    this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveTo(this.root);
    this.remainder--;
    assert this.remainder == 0;
  }

  private Node internalNodeHasNotEdgeStartingWithCharacter(final int index,
                                                         final char character,
                                                         Node previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode) {
    this.activePoint.addEdgeToActiveNode(character, new Edge(index, this.word.length(), null));
    previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode = this.activePoint.setSlinkToActiveNode(previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode);
    if(this.activePoint.activeNodeHasSlink()) {
        this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveToSlink();
    }
    else {
        this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveTo(this.root);
    }
    this.remainder--;
    return previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode;
  }

  private void activeEdgeHasCharacter() {
    this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveByOneCharacter();
    if(this.activePoint.pointsToTheEndOfActiveEdge()) {
        this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveToNextNodeOfActiveEdge();
    }
  }

  private Node edgeFromRootNodeHasNotCharacter(final int index,
                                             final char character,
                                             Node previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode) {
    final Node newNode = new Node(idGenerator++);
    this.activePoint.splitActiveEdge(this.word, newNode, index, character);
    previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode = this.activePoint.setSlinkTo(previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode, newNode);
    this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveToEdgeStartingWithAndByActiveLengthMinusOne(this.root,
            this.word.charAt(index - this.remainder + 2));
    this.activePoint = walkDown(index);
    this.remainder--;
    return previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode;
  }

  private Node edgeFromInternalNodeHasNotCharacter(final int index,
                                                 final char character,
                                                 Node previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode) {
    final Node newNode = new Node(idGenerator++);
    this.activePoint.splitActiveEdge(this.word, newNode, index, character);
    previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode = this.activePoint.setSlinkTo(previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode, newNode);
    if(this.activePoint.activeNodeHasSlink()) {
        this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveToSlink();
    }
    else {
        this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveTo(this.root);
    }
    this.activePoint = walkDown(index);
    this.remainder--;
    return previouslyAddedNodeOrAddedEdgeNode;
  }

  private ActivePoint walkDown(final int index) {
    while(!this.activePoint.pointsToActiveNode()
            && (this.activePoint.pointsToTheEndOfActiveEdge() || this.activePoint.pointsAfterTheEndOfActiveEdge())) {
        if(this.activePoint.pointsAfterTheEndOfActiveEdge()) {
            this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveToNextNodeOfActiveEdge(this.word, index);
        }
        else {
            this.activePoint = this.activePoint.moveToNextNodeOfActiveEdge();
        }
    }
    return this.activePoint;
  }

  public String toString(final String word) {
    return this.root.toString(word);
  }

  public boolean contains(final String suffix) {
    return this.root.contains(this.word, suffix);
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String[] words = {
            "abcabcabc$",
            "abc$",
            "abcabxabcd$",
            "abcabxabda$",
            "abcabxad$",
            "aabaaabb$",
            "aababcabcd$",
            "ababcabcd$",
            "abccba$",
            "mississipi$",
            "abacabadabacabae$",
            "abcabcd$",
            "00132220$"
    };
    Arrays.stream(words).forEach(word -> {
        System.out.println("Building suffix tree for word: " + word);
        final ST suffixTree = new ST(word);
        System.out.println("Suffix tree: " + suffixTree.toString(word));
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
            assert suffixTree.contains(word.substring(i)) : word.substring(i);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for the well explained tutorial by **@jogojapan**, I implemented the algorithm in Python.

A couple of minor problems mentioned by @jogojapan turns out to be more **sophisticated** than I have expected, and need to be treated very carefully. It cost me several days to get my implementation **robust enough** (I suppose). Problems and solutions are listed below:

1. **End with `Remainder > 0`** It turns out this situation can also happen **during the unfolding step**, not just the end of the entire algorithm. When that happens, we can leave the remainder, actnode, actedge, and actlength **unchanged**, end the current unfolding step, and start another step by either keep folding or unfolding depending on if the next char in the original string is on the current path or not.
2. **Leap Over Nodes:** When we follow a suffix link, update the active point, and then find that its active_length component does not work well with the new active_node. We have to **move forward** to the right place to split, or insert a leaf. This process might be **not that straightforward** because during the moving the actlength and actedge keep changing all the way, when you have to move back to the **root node**, the **actedge** and **actlength** could be **wrong** because of those moves. We need additional variable(s) to keep that information.

   [image]

The other two problems have somehow been pointed out by **@managonov**

3. **Split Could Degenerate** When trying to split an edge, sometime you'll find the split operation is right on a node. That case we only need add a new leaf to that node, take it as a standard edge split operation, which means the suffix links if there's any, should be maintained correspondingly.
4. **Hidden Suffix Links** There is another special case which is incurred by *problem 1* and *problem 2*. Sometimes we need to hop over several nodes to the right point for split, we might **surpass** the right point if we move by comparing the remainder string and the path labels. That case the suffix link will be neglected unintentionally, if there should be any. This could be avoided by **remembering the right point** when moving forward. The suffix link should be maintained if the split node already exists, or even the *problem 1* happens during a unfolding step.

Finally, my implementation in **Python** is as follows:

- [**Python**](https://github.com/mutux/Ukkonen-s-Suffix-Tree-Algorithm)

> **Tips:** *It includes a naive **tree printing** function in the code above, which is very important while debugging*. It saved me a lot of
>   time and is convenient for locating special cases.

Answer (score 6):

My intuition is as follows:

After k iterations of the main loop you have constructed a suffix tree which contains all suffixes of the complete string that start in the first k characters.

At the start, this means the suffix tree contains a single root node that represents the entire string (this is the only suffix that starts at 0).

After len(string) iterations you have a suffix tree that contains all suffixes.

During the loop the key is the active point.  My guess is that this represents the deepest point in the suffix tree that corresponds to a proper suffix of the first k characters of the string. (I think proper means that the suffix cannot be the entire string.)

For example, suppose you have seen characters 'abcabc'.  The active point would represent the point in the tree corresponding to the suffix 'abc'.

The active point is represented by (origin,first,last).
This means that you are currently at the point in the tree that you get to by starting at node origin and then feeding in the characters in string[first:last]

When you add a new character you look to see whether the active point is still in the existing tree.  If it is then you are done.
Otherwise you need to add a new node to the suffix tree at the active point, fallback to the next shortest match, and check again.

Note 1:
The suffix pointers give a link to the next shortest match for each node.

Note 2:
When you add a new node and fallback you add a new suffix pointer for the new node.
The destination for this suffix pointer will be the node at the shortened active point.
This node will either already exist, or be created on the next iteration of this fallback loop.

Note 3: The canonization part simply saves time in checking the active point.
For example, suppose you always used origin=0, and just changed first and last.
To check the active point you would have to follow the suffix tree each time along all the intermediate nodes.
It makes sense to cache the result of following this path by recording just the distance from the last node.

Can you give a code example of what you mean by "fix" bounding variables?

Health warning: I also found this algorithm particularly hard to understand so please realise that this intuition is likely to be incorrect in all important details...

Comment: One of the academic papers defines "proper" as meaning the "proper suffix" of a string doesn't contain its first character. Sometimes you call a whole substring a "suffix", but when defining the algorithm the terms "string" and "substring" and "suffix" get thrown around liberally and sometimes you need to be very clear what you mean by "suffix", so the term "proper suffix" excludes calling the whole thing a suffix. So a suffix substring of a string can be any legitimate substring and can have a proper suffix that isn't the same suffix. Because logic.

Answer (score 3):

Hi i have tried to implement the above explained implementation in ruby , please check it out.
it seems to work fine.

the only difference in the implementation is that , i have tried to use the edge object instead of just using symbols.

its also present at https://gist.github.com/suchitpuri/9304856

```
    require 'pry'


class Edge
    attr_accessor :data , :edges , :suffix_link
    def initialize data
        @data = data
        @edges = []
        @suffix_link = nil
    end

    def find_edge element
        self.edges.each do |edge|
            return edge if edge.data.start_with? element
        end
        return nil
    end
end

class SuffixTrees
    attr_accessor :root , :active_point , :remainder , :pending_prefixes , :last_split_edge , :remainder

    def initialize
        @root = Edge.new nil
        @active_point = { active_node: @root , active_edge: nil , active_length: 0}
        @remainder = 0
        @pending_prefixes = []
        @last_split_edge = nil
        @remainder = 1
    end

    def build string
        string.split("").each_with_index do |element , index|


            add_to_edges @root , element        

            update_pending_prefix element                           
            add_pending_elements_to_tree element
            active_length = @active_point[:active_length]

            # if(@active_point[:active_edge] && @active_point[:active_edge].data && @active_point[:active_edge].data[0..active_length-1] ==  @active_point[:active_edge].data[active_length..@active_point[:active_edge].data.length-1])
            #   @active_point[:active_edge].data = @active_point[:active_edge].data[0..active_length-1]
            #   @active_point[:active_edge].edges << Edge.new(@active_point[:active_edge].data)
            # end

            if(@active_point[:active_edge] && @active_point[:active_edge].data && @active_point[:active_edge].data.length == @active_point[:active_length]  )
                @active_point[:active_node] =  @active_point[:active_edge]
                @active_point[:active_edge] = @active_point[:active_node].find_edge(element[0])
                @active_point[:active_length] = 0
            end
        end
    end

    def add_pending_elements_to_tree element

        to_be_deleted = []
        update_active_length = false
        # binding.pry
        if( @active_point[:active_node].find_edge(element[0]) != nil)
            @active_point[:active_length] = @active_point[:active_length] + 1               
            @active_point[:active_edge] = @active_point[:active_node].find_edge(element[0]) if @active_point[:active_edge] == nil
            @remainder = @remainder + 1
            return
        end



        @pending_prefixes.each_with_index do |pending_prefix , index|

            # binding.pry           

            if @active_point[:active_edge] == nil and @active_point[:active_node].find_edge(element[0]) == nil

                @active_point[:active_node].edges << Edge.new(element)

            else

                @active_point[:active_edge] = node.find_edge(element[0]) if @active_point[:active_edge]  == nil

                data = @active_point[:active_edge].data
                data = data.split("")               

                location = @active_point[:active_length]


                # binding.pry
                if(data[0..location].join == pending_prefix or @active_point[:active_node].find_edge(element) != nil )                  


                else #tree split    
                    split_edge data , index , element
                end

            end
        end 
    end



    def update_pending_prefix element
        if @active_point[:active_edge] == nil
            @pending_prefixes = [element]
            return

        end

        @pending_prefixes = []

        length = @active_point[:active_edge].data.length
        data = @active_point[:active_edge].data
        @remainder.times do |ctr|
                @pending_prefixes << data[-(ctr+1)..data.length-1]
        end

        @pending_prefixes.reverse!

    end

    def split_edge data , index , element
        location = @active_point[:active_length]
        old_edges = []
        internal_node = (@active_point[:active_edge].edges != nil)

        if (internal_node)
            old_edges = @active_point[:active_edge].edges 
            @active_point[:active_edge].edges = []
        end

        @active_point[:active_edge].data = data[0..location-1].join                 
        @active_point[:active_edge].edges << Edge.new(data[location..data.size].join)


        if internal_node
            @active_point[:active_edge].edges << Edge.new(element)
        else
            @active_point[:active_edge].edges << Edge.new(data.last)        
        end

        if internal_node
            @active_point[:active_edge].edges[0].edges = old_edges
        end


        #setup the suffix link
        if @last_split_edge != nil and @last_split_edge.data.end_with?@active_point[:active_edge].data 

            @last_split_edge.suffix_link = @active_point[:active_edge] 
        end

        @last_split_edge = @active_point[:active_edge]

        update_active_point index

    end


    def update_active_point index
        if(@active_point[:active_node] == @root)
            @active_point[:active_length] = @active_point[:active_length] - 1
            @remainder = @remainder - 1
            @active_point[:active_edge] = @active_point[:active_node].find_edge(@pending_prefixes.first[index+1])
        else
            if @active_point[:active_node].suffix_link != nil
                @active_point[:active_node] = @active_point[:active_node].suffix_link               
            else
                @active_point[:active_node] = @root
            end 
            @active_point[:active_edge] = @active_point[:active_node].find_edge(@active_point[:active_edge].data[0])
            @remainder = @remainder - 1     
        end
    end

    def add_to_edges root , element     
        return if root == nil
        root.data = root.data + element if(root.data and root.edges.size == 0)
        root.edges.each do |edge|
            add_to_edges edge , element
        end
    end
end

suffix_tree = SuffixTrees.new
suffix_tree.build("abcabxabcd")
binding.pry
```