# Ukkonen's suffix tree algorithm with Leaf-label

Tags: algorithm, suffix-tree

I have read the post [Ukkonen's suffix tree algorithm in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english). But it is unclear how to get the leaf label using this algorithm.

In suffix tree the leaf-label is the number i such that S[i..n] is the suffix that the leaf represent. If I want such a label will it still be O(n) for the total complexity ?

And how to do it ?

Comment: Yes it can be done in linear time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Record another `L` variable in each node to store the sum of `end - start` of all ancestors. This value indicates the length of the substring ended at a particular node i.e. for leaf it is the length of the suffix. `L` is updated whenever a tree node is added or a tree node is split.

Then the leaf-label is just `n - leaf.L`