# Ukkonen's suffix tree algorithm, what is necessary?

Tags: c++, data-structures, suffix-tree

Yes I have read this: [Ukkonen's suffix tree algorithm in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english)

It is a great explanation of the algorithm but it is not so much the algorithm itself that is killing me but rather the data structure used to implement it.

I need the data structure to be as minimal and as fast as possible and I have seen many implementations using only Nodes, some with only edges, some with edges and nodes, etc. Then there are variations, a website I was reading claimed that a node need not have a pointer to its parent, and other places don't account for how children of a node are managed.

My idea is to have a Node structure with int start, and int * end (points to the current end or phase i). Each node will have a suffix_link pointer, a pointer to its parent, and a pointer to a vector containing its child nodes.

My question is, are these things sufficient and necessary to implement a suffix tree? Can I minimize it in any way? I haven't seen an implementation with children in vectors yet so I am skeptical as to my own thinking. Could someone explain what one would need to implement a suffix tree in this manner using only nodes?

Comment: Just a side note, have a look at suffix arrays also. They are said to be much easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Following may be helpful:

[Ukkonen’s Suffix Tree Construction](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ukkonens-suffix-tree-construction-part-6/)

Here we have 
1. start, end to represent edge label 
2. suffix link 
3. an array for children

Answer (score -1):

When i have to implement that algorithm the better explained document was the original [Ukkonen paper](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1.pdf) and there's one [newer with images](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1withFigs.pdf).

Yes in this documents are all the inside to implement Ukkonen's Suffix Tree algorithm.