# How to find substring in large amount strings?

Tags: algorithm

I have 1,000,000 strings with different lengths(the largest length is limited), I want to find all sub stirngs. Is there a good algorithm？
for example,

1. s1:abcd
2. s2:bcd
3. s3:cd
4. s4:bcde

substrings are:

1. s2 in s1
2. s2 in s4
3. s3 in s2
4. s3 in s4

Comment: If i am not mistaken you mean s2 in s1+s2 and so on right?

Comment: Just a thought: Use a Trie (prefix tree) structure. After adding all strings, you should be able to get your substring list by mere traversal.

Comment: I mean s2 is in s1 and s4

Comment: There are O(n^2) results. You don't want them all.

Comment: how to reduce comparation count when sub strings  have no common prefix?

Comment: You may want to take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english